# update iOS on iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am having iPhone 3G with iOS version 3.1.3. I am going to update iOS 3.1.3 to 4.1.

After update iOS 4.1, can I restore it again to iOS 3.1.3 ?

Will it get any issue after restore the version ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jfalexvijay, this forum is for questions related to programming, not questions related to how the performance of your device will be affected if you upgrade your OS.

Comment: @Brian: Was my initial thought, too... but then testing on those devices is important, making the the last two questions valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3G is borderline to update in my opinion, but with the latest versions it should have become better (you probably want to go directly to 4.2). 3G won't have all new features anyway.

If you need to test on it you don't have an alternative anyway. For personal use I'd recommend a new device. :-)

Restoring to a previous version is officially not supported. People got lucky with it, though. It is not guaranteed that you have the *exact* same state as before, though, which diminishes value as a testing device.

Comment: Wait about 10 minutes, the 4.2 is coming out. I had a 3G and after upgrading to 4.0 it was so laggy! Personally, I wouldn't update.

Comment: They improved performance on the 3G a great deal with 4.1, and also with 4.2 - you should re-consider an uprade as it's much better than it was with 4.0.